# Rss feed with different language utf8

Tags: php, utf-8, rss

i am trying to work with the following feed. http://www.amaderbarisal.com/feed

so as you can see its in bangladeshi.

বরিশাল :: বরিশালে প্রশাসনিক কয়েকটি পদে রদবদল করা হয়েছে। বৃহস্পতিবার জনপ্রশাসন

i am running this function to pulling the data from the rss feed.

```
$source_xml = utf8_encode(file_get_contents($url));
$source_xml = simplexml_load_string(str_replace('content:encoded', 'description', $source_xml), 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($source_xml);
echo "<pre>";
```

ok there is something happening in the simple xml function that is altering all the data because i get outputted to following.

Ã Â¦Â¬Ã Â¦Â°Ã Â¦Â¿Ã Â¦Â¶Ã Â¦Â¾Ã Â¦Â² :: Ã Â¦Â¬Ã Â¦Â°Ã Â¦Â¿Ã Â¦Â¶Ã Â¦Â¾Ã Â¦Â²Ã Â§Â‡ Ã Â¦ÂªÃ Â§ÂÃ Â¦Â°Ã Â¦Â¶Ã Â¦Â¾Ã Â¦Â¸Ã Â¦Â¨Ã Â¦Â¿Ã Â¦Â• Ã Â¦Â•Ã Â§ÂŸÃ Â§Â‡Ã Â¦Â•Ã Â¦Â

Can someone explain why this maybe happening???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the description for [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/utf8_encode):

> utf8_encode — Encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8

Is your input in ISO-8859-1 as required by this function? In Firefox, you can just use the "View page info" entry in the context menu, and it displays *UTF-8*. To sum up:

- You can't convert *from ISO-8859-1* because the source text does not use such encoding.
- You don't need to convert *to UTF-8* because the source text is already using such encoding.

Comment: Ok its working now thanks guys i used the following to run a check.

Comment: $source_xml = file_get_contents($url); echo mb_detect_encoding($source_xml); ii was in utf8 so their is now need for the utf8_encode() function aswell

Answer (score 0):

Check the  character encoding setting inside of your php.ini. This is set to default standard Latin encoding (ISO-8859). You will need to change this if you haven't already.

Are you outputting in an environment that has the font support for Bangla characters?

Comment: Cheers R Ghosh going to check this now